select runtimeClassName for kubeflow notebooks
I configured my kubeflow gpu server recently, but the GPU does not get detected in there - the reason is cluster using wrong runtime.
I prefer not to change the default runtime system-wide and tried modifying the "PodDefault" list out there in manifest to add gpu runtime option like that:
apiVersion: kubeflow.org/v1alpha1
kind: PodDefault
metadata:
  name: gpu-runtime-nv
  namespace: kubeflow
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      gpu-runtime-nv: "true"
  desc: "Select nvidia runtime"
  runtimeClassName: nvidia


I expected, since there was an example with volumeMounts, that any standard part of spec could be injected that way before starting a notebook, but I am getting an error indicating that the custom resource definition for PodDefault doesn't understand spec named runtimeClassName. I don't quite understand CRD of that magnitude so I don't know how to make it work, but perhaps there is a simpler way of achieving what I want.
Bottom line:
how to specify runtimeClassName for kubeflow notebooks when starting them?

As you mentioned, the PodDefault CRD doesn't allow runtimeClassName in the spec.
Luckily, Kubeflow ships with a Notebook CRD which allows you to specify the runtimeClassName like so:
apiVersion: kubeflow.org/v1
kind: Notebook
metadata:
  name: nvidia-runtime-notebook
  namespace: kubeflow-user-example-com
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      runtimeClassName: nvidia
      containers:
        - name: notebook
          image: kubeflownotebookswg/jupyter-scipy:v1.8.0
          resources:
            limits:
              nvidia.com/gpu: 1
          volumeMounts:
            - name: workspace
              mountPath: /home/jovyan
      volumes:
        - name: workspace
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-pvc

If you're unsure which image to use (or any other value, e.g. CPU) you can go through the Kubeflow UI for creating a Notebook and use the available values there as a guideline (as shown in the below screenshot).

However, I would recommend using the kubeflownotebookswg/jupyter-tensorflow-cuda-full:v1.8.0 image if you're planning on using any GPU features, or you may receive errors like Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.

Thanks! I used a subsystem named kyverno to inject nvidia runtime to new pods at the creation time which got it working. I'll try to implement your solution and compare it - if it works as intended, it would make a cleaner system

I'm glad you managed to find a solution. But if you do end up finding my solution helpful, can you accept my answer? I appreciate it!

defining crd with namespace: kubeflow-user-example-com makes it exclusive to a specific user - every new user would need to get this specific notebook added through the manifest making the solution difficult to scale - am I missing something?

You're right that by default the notebook is only accessible by the owner of the namespace, but you can add contributors to that namespace with read/edit access. I'm not sure how it would work in a namespace not owned by a specific user, but you might find this link useful.
